# How to Open Calendar App on a specific calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I want to open up the Calendar application from an android application but with a specific `calendarId`.

My code:

```
final Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

startActivityForResult(calIntent, RESULT_CODE_OPEN);
```

But the intent open with the last Calendar used. I want open a specific one with his calendar ID.

How can I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents
it is not possible.

Answer (score 11):

***A bit of history:*** *Looking into Calendar App sources, i found [this section](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2d72f6bed6a0eeaddbda08393063fe873c1c7922/AndroidManifest.xml#L99-L114) of manifest which indicates what class handles Intent.ACTION_EDIT, [EditEventActivity.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2d72f6bed6a0eeaddbda08393063fe873c1c7922/src/com/android/calendar/event/EditEventActivity.java). Then I found [this](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2d72f6bed6a0eeaddbda08393063fe873c1c7922/src/com/android/calendar/event/EditEventActivity.java#L156) line; `calendarId` is obtained from extra data. so...*

#### Open an EditEvent - *(answer to original question)*

Put an extra long on the Intent with key `CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID` and the corresponding `calendarId` like this sample:

```
long calendarId = 1234; // here goes your calendar Id

final Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
       .setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
       .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);

startActivityForResult(calIntent, RESULT_CODE_OPEN);
```

#### Open the Calendar app with the <strike>month</strike> week view on specific calendar - *(answer to bounty question - PART 1)*

This approach is a bit different. Before open Calendar app, you should make invisible all calendars but no the selected one. So, I've created a helper function to do exactly that.

```
private void makeAllCalendarsInvisibleExcept(long calendarId) {
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
    updateValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 0);

    // make all invisible
    getContentResolver().update(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
            updateValues, null, null);

    updateValues.clear();
    updateValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);


    // make calendarId visible
    getContentResolver().update(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
            updateValues, where, null);
}
```

And here how to setup it:

```
makeAllCalendarsInvisibleExcept(calendarId);
Intent calIntent = new Intent();
// for google calendar, first parameter should be "com.google.android.calendar"
// this is intended for android calendar.
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
calIntent.setComponent(cn);
startActivityForResult(calIntent, 4567);
```

AFAIK, no way to open month view. But research never ends, i will do an update ASAP.

In the DemoApp I've created two extra helper methods to push and restore calendars visibility state. Take a look arround `pushCalendarVisibility` and `restoreCalendarVisibility` and `onActivityResult`

Note: I've tested the app with and without Google calendar installed. AFAIK on Google Calendar shown only DAY view, not WEEK neither MONTH.

**In all cases shown only events on selected calendar.**

#### Get `calendarId` and `Account Name` - *(answer to bounty question - PART 2)*

`calendarId` abd `Account Name` can be obtained using CalendarContract.Calendars, like this:

```
// since API14 
Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
};

Cursor calendarCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
while (calendarCursor.moveToNext()) {

    // calendarId
    long calendarId = calendarCursor.getLong(0);

    // get visibility, warning: if calendar is not visible Intent.ACTION_EDIT doesn't work.
    boolean calendarVisible = calendarCursor.getInt(1) == 1;

    // get if it's owned, warning: if calendar is not owned Intent.ACTION_EDIT doesn't work.
    boolean calendarOwned = calendarCursor.getInt(2) == CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER;

    // get calendar display name
    String calendarName = calendarCursor.getString(3);

    // get account name
    String accountName = calendarCursor.getString(4);

    // do something

}
```

Note: There are more available options for calendar *projection*, advice read [`CalendarContract.Calendars`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html)

### Limitations

This features is available since API Level 14, Android 4.0 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)

### Demo App

Complete example in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/rnrneverdies/CalendarDemo). (Android Studio 1.0.0 project)
Requires Calendars synced and must be owned by the account and must be visible.
*UPDATE: example up to date*

*Tested on Android 4.1.1 and Android 5.0 Lollipop Preview*